# I have two django sites. How can I tell if a user is already authenticated on one of them?

Tags: python, django, authentication, single-sign-on

I have two sites that are very closely linked and both are built with django. They have the same set of users.

How would I tell on one site if the user is authenticated on the other?

Comment: try http://code.google.com/p/django-openid/

Comment: if they are both on the same server, django allows you to open two databases so you could share the authentication tables. Seehttps://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleDatabaseSupport

Comment: Since django user authentication depends on django session, if the websites are in different domains (not just different subdomains) user's login status on site A will not visible on site B (as they each has different cookie). I never try it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

Use a session backend that uses a common store (a database, or redis), which is accessible to both; or openid as suggested by alf.